# How to throw User Exceptions from MFP 8 Java Adapter to Client?

Tags: java, exception, ibm-mobilefirst

I wanted to know, if there is a way to throw User Exceptions from MFP 8 Java Adapter to Client. I tried to throw some exceptions from the server and I get a common error. "Unexpected error... check server".
Is there a way where we can throw exceptions to the client, so that it can be handled at the client in the failure blocks?

Only if there is a server crash, it is handled in the failure block of the client API methods.

Comment: Can you provide an actual scenario you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

[Java adapters](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/java-adapters/) in MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 are essentially JAX-RS applications. As such you can use the "[exception mapper](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6754)" concept in JAX-RS to define custom responses.

Read more in the JAX-RS documentation: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html#JAX-RSBasics-Exceptionhandling

You can also find various examples online.